# Adminlte darkmode is not working on Datatable properly (Razor Pages / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, razor-pages, adminlte

When I am rendering the Datatable using Ajax call on fly, I am getting this output. The darkmode styles are not applied to rows.

[image]

but when I am using hardcode datatable using simple html in razor page. The colors are applied and the output is according to expectations.
[image]

Any Suggestions will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: have you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I did a workaround. I have added a darkmodetoggle function, that will take the id of required table and toggle the classes of childrens for th, td, tr and all required tags.

Comment: I had the same issue when I do the theming. now i have solved by removing fixed header cdn of datatable